# Will returning an update method from a Firebase function satisfy the promise requirement and automatically log events?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function that makes a write to Firestore when a user logs out of a client. I don't need to return anything to the client and I don't want to handle any errors (as of right now) except for logging to console (which I think is done automatically). Therefore, can I forego `then()` and `catch()` and just return the call to update the database (as follows)?

```
export const userDidSignOut = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const userId = data.userId
    const userSettingsUpdate = {
        "private.fcmToken": null
    }

    return admin.firestore().collection("userSettings").doc(userId).update(userSettingsUpdate)
})
```

1. Does this satisfy Firebase's requirement to properly handle all promises?
2. Will this log successes and failures to the Functions log automatically?
3. Documentation says I can request asynchronous (non-HTTPS) background functions to retry on failure but I'm confused by that statement. AFAIK the above function (which is called from within an iOS app) is a background function (a non-HTTP-request function) but it's still an `https` function. Does this function qualify for automatic retry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firestore `update` method returns a promise that resolves when the write is completed on the server. So if you return that from your Cloud Function, the Cloud Function will be terminated when the write completes. Since this is the only exit path in your code, you're indeed returning a value or promise from each path.

Success and failure of this promise will be logged in the Cloud Functions logs.

`onCall` functions are wrappers around HTTPS functions, and are not background functions. They cannot be automatically retried by the Cloud Functions engine. If you want the callable function retried for whatever reason, you will have to handle that in your client-side application code.

Comment: I thought there were 2 types of functions as it relates to terminating them: HTTP triggers and background triggers. HTTP triggers must terminate by sending a response and background triggers must return a promise. If my function is really an HTTP-triggered function, why must I not send a response instead of returning a promise?

Comment: Because `onCall` functions **return a value**, instead of **sending a response**. Essentially: your code is wrapped in a HTTP function by Firebase, that catches the return value and then sends the response (immediately or once the promise resolves) on your behalf. The client-side `firebase-functions` SDK grabs the response it receives and unpacks that for you.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. One last thing: this function can fail in two ways, correct? It can either fail as a function itself or it could fail from within the function (the database write could fail). If it fails as a function itself (maybe network conectivity), the client that called it (iOS app) would get that error. But if the write within the function failed, does my function (how it's currently written) convey that error to the client? Will this returned promise tell the client success or failure?

Comment: As far as I know a rejected promise will translate to an error same as a wire problem, but it should be pretty simple to check that with `return Promise.reject()`.